# WebGL is not rendering 3d objects properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, webgl, render

I have a generator of 3d objects in a canvas context.

The rendering is carried out with the painter's algorithm. However, I need a more accurate approach for my project.

Therefore, I have implemented a WebGL renderer. The idea is to transform the objects generated in the canvas context to the WebGL context ( I have two overlayed canvases for this purpose)  in order to render them accurately with regards to the HSA (hidden surface algorithm) problem.

I have a function that transforms the canvas coordinates to clip coordinates, and that sets up the different elements and peculiarities required by WebGL, basically, the function prepares the 3d objects to be rendered by WebGL.

As I also need the segments of the shapes to be rendered, my approach consists in creating a buffer, in which all the coordinates of all the objects are stored, together with the coordinates of the segments of these objects, which will be represented and drawn as thin 3d squares (that is, each line will be formed by 2 thin coupled-up triangles, whose vertices and positions will be determined beforehand in canvas coordinates).

So far I am only testing and have coded the rendering of the shapes without lines. The problem is, it is not working properly. Triangles are drawn wrongly, with points and positions that either do not exist in the buffer or are mistaken.

**Here is what should be drawn:** (this cube is rendered in the canvas with the painter's algorithm)
[image: :]

Here is the colored silhouette that is drawn, however:
[image]

If only drawing the face 0 with LINE_LOOP
[image]

soon things get pretty messed up, face 0 + face 1 (face 1 is obviously being mistakenly drawn)
[image]

3 faces

[image]

Things get worse with more complicated objects (notice that this one is not perfectly rendered either)
[image]

[image]

I do not really know what is happening. My knowledge of WebGL and of 3d graphics, in general, is pretty limited, not to say inexistent. I do not have studies in computer science or any IT-related domain either. I just need a function to render my javascript 3d objects properly for a personal project. Here is the code that I am using:

```js
function webglPrepare(escena){ //Takes canvas 3d objects as inputs, and outputs the arrays requiered by webgl; vertices, indices, and colors
    var zprep=2000;
 var nbVertices; var FacesHSA=[];  var cont=0; var zmean=[]; var temp=[]; var vertices=[]; var cont2=0; var indices=[]; var sumer=0; var controlador=0;
 var colors=[]; var cont3=0;  var prueba=0; //These variables are irrelevant
 
 
 object_for:   for(var i=0; i<escena.length; i++){ //this is irrelevant
        
  face_for:  for(var a=0; a<escena[i].arrayObjetos.length; a++){    //Just looping over all the objects 
      
 check_loop:  for(var ff=0; ff<escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces.length; ff++){ //for each face of the object
 
 if(escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces[ff].vertices.length==3){   //If the face has 3 vertices, then
  indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1;   //We setup the indices array, which will store the indices to form the triangles, needed by webgl
   indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1;                  
      indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1;   
    
    
 }
  else if(escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces[ff].vertices.length==4){ //The same, but if the face has 4 vertices. I do not have faces longer than that
      
   indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1; 
   indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1;                  
      indices[cont2]=sumer; cont2=cont2+1;    
    
    indices[cont2]=indices[cont2-3];  cont2=cont2+1;
      indices[cont2]=indices[cont2-2];   cont2=cont2+1; sumer=sumer+1;
       indices[cont2]=sumer;  sumer=sumer+1; cont2=cont2+1; 
                    
                    
      
  }
     
        for (var j = 0; j < (nbVertices = escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces[ff].vertices.length) ; j++) { // For each vertex of the face.
     
   vertices[cont]  =  escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].vertices[j].x/ gl.canvas.width  *  2 - 1;  //The x coordinate is transformed to clip coordinates
 
                    cont=cont+1;
   vertices[cont]  = escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces[ff].vertices[j].y/ gl.canvas.height * -2 + 1;  //Same with the y coordinate 
   
  
   cont=cont+1;
         vertices[cont]  = escena[i].arrayObjetos[a].faces[ff].vertices[j].z;  //Same with the Z. Zprep is an arbitrary Zmax value, used to
                                           //Used to carry out the transformation
  if(vertices[cont]>=0){ if(vertices[cont]>zprep){alert("error en Z, es mayor");} vertices[cont]=vertices[cont]/zprep;       } 
 else if(vertices[cont]<=0){ if(vertices[cont]>zprep){alert("error en Z, es menor");} vertices[cont]= -(vertices[cont]/zprep);     } 
 //Supuestamente el z- es el mas cercano y el + el mas
    cont=cont+1;                               //The colours are also prepared
                    //cont=cont+3;  
      colors[cont3]=0;
    colors[cont3+1]=0;
       colors[cont3+2]=0;   
       cont3=cont3+3;
        }
        
  
 
    }
  }}
  
    
    webgl2(vertices, indices, colors); //Once everything is ready, we call the WebGL renderer
}
```

The webgl2 function (which does the rendering)

```js
function webgl2(vertices, indices, colors){
  
        // Create and store data into vertex buffer
         var vertex_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
         gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  

         // Create and store data into color buffer
         var color_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
         gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

         // Create and store data into index buffer
         var index_buffer = gl.createBuffer ();
         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
         gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

         /*=================== SHADERS =================== */

         var vertCode = 'attribute vec3 position;'+
            'uniform mat4 Pmatrix;'+
            'uniform mat4 Vmatrix;'+
            'uniform mat4 Mmatrix;'+
            'attribute vec3 color;'+//the color of the point
            'varying vec3 vColor;'+
            'void main(void) { '+//pre-built function
               'gl_Position = Pmatrix*Vmatrix*Mmatrix*vec4(position, 1.);'+
               'vColor = color;'+
            '}';

         var fragCode = 'precision mediump float;'+
            'varying vec3 vColor;'+
            'void main(void) {'+
               'gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.);'+
            '}';

         var vertShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
         gl.shaderSource(vertShader, vertCode);
         gl.compileShader(vertShader);

         var fragShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
         gl.shaderSource(fragShader, fragCode);
         gl.compileShader(fragShader);

         var shaderprogram = gl.createProgram();
         gl.attachShader(shaderprogram, vertShader);
         gl.attachShader(shaderprogram, fragShader);
         gl.linkProgram(shaderprogram);

         /*======== Associating attributes to vertex shader =====*/
         var _Pmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Pmatrix");
         var _Vmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Vmatrix");
         var _Mmatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderprogram, "Mmatrix");

         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
         var _position = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderprogram, "position");
         gl.vertexAttribPointer(_position, 3, gl.FLOAT, false,0,0);
         gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_position);

         gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, color_buffer);
         var _color = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderprogram, "color");
         gl.vertexAttribPointer(_color, 3, gl.FLOAT, false,0,0) ;
         gl.enableVertexAttribArray(_color);
         gl.useProgram(shaderprogram);

 var proj_matrix = get_projection(40, canvas.width/canvas.height, 1, 100); //The parameters inserted here are not used. 
 // Right now, get_projection returns an identity matrix
         var mo_matrix = [ 1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1 ];
         var view_matrix = [ 1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1 ];

    
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);

        gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9);
       //    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
            gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      //     gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Pmatrix, false, proj_matrix);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Vmatrix, false, view_matrix);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_Mmatrix, false, mo_matrix);

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_buffer);
     
     //  gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_LOOP, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
   
 
 gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length  , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
//  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, indices.length);
     //  gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, vertices.length/3);
  
    
 // gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, 56);
}
```

The get_projection function:

```js
function get_projection(angle, a, zMin, zMax) {
            var ang = Math.tan((angle*.5)*Math.PI/180);//angle*.5
 /*         return [
               0.5/ang, 0 , 0, 0,
               0, 0.5*a/ang, 0, 0,
               0, 0, -(zMax+zMin)/(zMax-zMin), -1,
               0, 0, (-2*zMax*zMin)/(zMax-zMin), 0 
               ];  */
     return [
               1, 0 , 0, 0,
               0, 1 , 0, 0,
               0, 0, 1, 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1 
               ]; 
         }
```

It might probably be due to several errors instead of just 1, I just can't find any of them.

Comment: if you really don't care of what is used and is not a part of learning, you can go with three.js instead of this.

Comment: "I just need a function to render my javascript 3d objects properly for a personal project."  I concur with @pravin, that three.js will be an easier path than building the 3d transformations from scratch.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57127276/7696162 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57173990/7696162 for some basic examples that render some objects and let you orbit around them to view from various angles.